# Why do I sometimes see a downloading 'pie' icon when viewing photostream photos?

Tags: icloud, ios, photo-stream

it normally shows in the bottom corner as a sort of 'pie' that fills up as the picture is downloaded, similar to the 'app downloading' pie when viewing a downloading app on the home page/s

prior to this the picture resolution is terrible

Answer (score 3):

That device has only a thumbnail and is indicating the progress fetching a higher resolution image.

From [Apple KB - My Photo Stream FAQ](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201317)

> **What resolution are My Photo Stream photos?**
>
> On a Mac or PC, your photos are downloaded and stored in full resolution. On iPhone, iPad, iPod touch, and Apple TV, your photos are delivered in a device-optimized resolution that speeds downloads and saves storage space. Dimensions will vary, but an optimized version of a photo taken by a standard point-and-shoot camera will have a 2048 x 1536 pixel resolution when pushed to your devices. Panoramic photos can be up to 5400 pixels wide.

Comment: This is odd as it also happened when I was roaming but I have data roaming turned off and was not connected to wifi at the time

Comment: I'm not fully au fait with how the new Photos structure works - there is a possibility it had the full image already & was taking its time thinking about fetching it. I'm not really sure if/how it would make that distinction. Perhaps it tried to fetch, found it couldn't, then instead fully fetched its perhaps half-res cached version instead - which wouldn't be noticeable on a phone. [as you can tell, I'm guessing a bit ;)

Comment: It always shows the pie. Even if you aren't connected to a network. Once it figures out that it doesn't have a network connection, it will just show a ! inside the pie.